# Setting static number of ticks for a chart in NVD3 and ClojureScript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, clojure, nvd3.js, clojurescript

I'm currently trying to create a chart that, on the x axis displays the days of the week beginning with Monday, and on the y axis display the week (ie Jan 15, Jan 22, etc)

I'm having trouble making the x-axis always display the 7 days. For example, if my data *only* has a piece of data for Monday, I would like all 7 days to appear on the axis regardless.

Here is what I have so far:

```
(defn bubble-chart [a] 
  (.addGraph js/nv (fn []
                     (let [chart          (.. js/nv -models scatterChart)
                           width          500
                           x              (doto (js/d3.time.scale.) (.domain #js [0 6]) (.range #js [0 width]))
                           formatWeekFunc (.. js/d3 -time (format "%b %d"))
                           week           ["Mon" "Tues" "Wed" "Thurs" "Fri" "Sat" "Sun"]]

                       (.. chart -xAxis 
                           (scale x)
                           (axisLabel "Day of the week") 
                           (ticks 7)
                           ;(tickSize 16 0)
                           (tickValues #js [0 1 2 3 4 5 6])
                           (tickFormat (fn [d] (nth week d))))


                       (. chart (yScale (js/d3.time.scale.utc.)))
                       (.. chart -yAxis 
                           (axisLabel "Week") 
                           (ticks (.. js/d3 -time -monday) 1)
                           (tickFormat (fn [d] (formatWeekFunc (js/Date. d)))))


                     (let [my-data @a]
                         (println (str "my-data " my-data))
                         (.. js/d3 (select "#testDiv svg")

                             (datum (clj->js my-data))
                             (call chart)))))))
```

I understand that I should be using `x` like I do and setting the xAxis to `scale(x)` but I am not sure if all of my syntax is correct for ClojureScript in D3 or if I am even doing it correctly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the answer. To manipulate nvd3 with clojurescript you need to make sure that all of the nvd3 ["options"](https://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/documentation.html#scatterChart) are formatted like this:

```
(. chart (forceX #js [0 1 2 3 4 5 6]))
(.. chart -xAxis 
    (axisLabel "Day of the week") 
    (tickValues (.range js/d3 0 6 1))
    (tickFormat (fn [d] (nth week d))))

;(. chart (yRange #js [chart.height 0]))
(. chart (yDomain #js [chart.height 0]))
(. chart (yScale (js/d3.time.scale.utc.)))
```

They cannot be put in the let[].

So to answer the original question - it can be achieved with `(.chart (forceX #js [yourRange]))`.